# Should we write dependent: destroy on a join table model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, models, has-many-through

I have 3 models A, B and C. B is the join table between A & C. The association is made through a `has_many :through`.

I was wondering if the non-join-table models (A & C in my case) should have `dependent: :destroy` with the join table association or if it's taken care automatically by rails ?

Is it the same answer for a HABTM association ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because you can delete records without instantiating them which wouldn't call dependent destroy and you'd be left with orphaned records.

For example [delete_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all)

Instead if you add a foreign key the database will handle the delete and it doesn't matter if you instantiate the object or not.

For example in a migration you can add

```
def change
  add_foreign_key :as, :bs, on_delete: :cascade
end
```

Or in the table creation migration

```
t.belongs_to :a, foreign_key: { on_delete: :cascade }
```

Comment: Indeed, I just tested in the console, no need to specify ```dependent: :destroy``` for the join table ```has_many``` association, rails seems to take care of destroying the appropriate data in the join table automagically.